# Find the four vertices of the cube, starting with $(1, 1, 1)$, that form a regular tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, 3d

The eight vertices of a cube centered at $(0, 0, 0)$ of side length $2$ are at $(±1, ±1, ±1)$.
Find the four vertices of the cube, starting with $(1, 1, 1)$, that form a regular tetrahedron. Confirm your answer by finding the length of an edge and explaining why all edges have the same length.

I was trying to choose any three other vertices from the cube, ensuring that they are equidistant from the starting vertex $(1, 1, 1)$. To form an equilateral triangle, those are:

$$(1, -1, -1),(-1, -1, 1),(-1, 1, -1)$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> In the hope of helping you verify your own answer: Have you made a sketch?

Comment: You say your three other vertices are equidistant from the starting vertex.  Are they also this distance from each other?  If so, then you have an equilateral tetrahedron with four equilateral triangles.